# How to emulate REPEAT() in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, function, simulation

Most relational databases have some sort of `REPEAT()` string function, for instance:

```
SELECT REPEAT('abc', 3)
```

Would yield

```
abcabcabc
```

SQLite on the other hand has a very limited feature set. The functions supported by SQLite are listed here:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Can `REPEAT()` be emulated with the functions available in SQLite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer combines [Shiplu Mokaddim's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54031187/3499840) ["printf character substitution repetition"](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) with the "replace" of [Steve Broberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792334/3499840) and [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11568516/3499840):

```
sqlite> SELECT replace(printf('%.' || 5 || 'c', '/'),'/','My string ');
My string My string My string My string My string
```

It's also easy to derive the number of repetitions from table data. Here's an example using a common table expression:

```
sqlite> WITH cte(string, reps) AS
    ..>   (SELECT * FROM (values ('alpha ', 1),('bravo ', 5),('charlie ', 3) ) )
    ..> SELECT *, replace(printf('%.' || reps || 'c', '/'), '/', string) FROM cte;
alpha       1           alpha
bravo       5           bravo bravo bravo bravo bravo
charlie     3           charlie charlie charlie
```

Comment: I've benchmarked your approach and compared it with the [`zeroblob`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792334/521799) approach. [Yours seems to be slightly faster on SQLite 3.30.1 via JDBC](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10157)

Comment: N.B. The replace approach uses less opcodes (10) vs printf (14).

Answer (score 10):

A solution was inspired by this answer to a related question, here:

[How to emulate LPAD/RPAD with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6576343/521799)

I wanted to share this on Stack Overflow, as this may be useful to other SQLite users. The solution goes like this:

```
-- X = string
-- Y = number of repetitions

replace(substr(quote(zeroblob((Y + 1) / 2)), 3, Y), '0', X)
```

Answer (score 7):

If its a **single character** you want to repeat, you can use `printf` function.

Bellow is an example where `x` is repeated `10` times. The key is the `*` in the format string which specifies that the width of the field will be passed as a parameter:

```
sqlite> select printf('%.*c', 10, 'x');
xxxxxxxxxx
```

To repeat multiple characters you can then `replace()` each `x` by the longer string, much as in Lukas's answer above.

Answer (score 4):

A simplified version of @Lukas Eder's solution using hex() instead of quote:

```
-- X = string
-- Y = number of repetitions

replace(hex(zeroblob(Y)), '00', X)
```