# Using GLOB to match each character in an SQLite TEXT field

Tags: sqlite, glob

I have an `TEXT` field in an SQLite table that is required to be exactly 17 characters long. Let's call it `myfield`.

For any arbitrary row in this table, how can we use SQLite's `GLOB` operator within a `CHECK` bracket to match each character in the `myfield` column entry (and, if possible, enforce the 17 character constraint)?

Every character in this entry can be any digit `0 - 9`, or any uppercase letter excluding `I`, `O`, and `Q`. Also, the 9th character of the `myfield` entry can only be a digit `0 - 9` or the letter `X`, but I'm still trying to get the previous conditions first.

**What have I tried?**

1. `CHECK(myfield GLOB '[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{17}')` - This doesn't work, and I think it's because `GLOB` doesn't support the curly bracket notation - correct me if I'm wrong.
2. `CHECK(length(myfield) == 17 AND myfield GLOB '[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]')` - Also doesn't work, presumably because the second check condition only matches a single character, contradicting the first.
3. I'm convinced there's a simpler solution than setting up 17 check conditions for each character in the string!

Comment: If you can add the `REGEXP` user defined function ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query)), then you may use: `CHECK(myfield REGEXP '^[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{17}$')`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That would be wonderful - and I have a working solution with `REGEXP` - but the confines of the question I'm trying to work out requires that I stick with `GLOB`.

Comment: You could look at the string function trim() and see if you can do something with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite there is a [*trick*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792334/10498828) to emulate a function like MySql's [`REPEAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_repeat) which returns a string repeated *n* times.
So by:

```
REPLACE(HEX(ZEROBLOB(8)), '00', '[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]')
```

you get the string `'[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]'` repeated 8 times:

```
[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]
```

You can use this trick to construct (by concatenations) the string that you need after `GLOB` in your `CHECK` constraint:

```
CHECK(myfield GLOB 
                REPLACE(HEX(ZEROBLOB(8)), '00', '[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]') || 
                '[X0-9]' || 
                REPLACE(HEX(ZEROBLOB(8)), '00', '[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]')
)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c4b544f1be71873da8bc2cf9f5d7bc9b).

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy and paste it for 17 times

CHECK (myfield GLOB "[A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][X0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9][A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]")

And at the 9th element, just key in X0-9, so "the 9th character of the myfield entry can only be a digit 0 - 9 or the letter X" can be checked too
By doing this, you can also enforce the 17 characters constraint