# like statement not working in sql check statement in sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm working on a project and I need to create a table with phone number, I want to check that all the characters are digits by using the regex '^[0-9]{10}$' in a check statement while creating the table, but when I enter any phone number like '0522233355' I got error in check statement, which contains the regex, I'm attaching my code:

```
def create_table():
    customers_table = """
    create table if not exists Customers(
        phone_number nvarchar(10) primary key,
        first_name nvarchar(15),
        last_name nvarchar(15),
        city nvarchar(20),
        address nvarchar(50),
        backup_phone nvarchar(10),
        password nvarchar(20),
        check (length(phone_number) == 10),
        check (phone_number not like backup_phone),
        check (phone_number like '^[0-9]{10}$'),
        check (length(password) >= 8 and length(password) <= 20),
        check (password like '^.{8,20}$')
     )
    """
    
    products_table = """
    create table if not exists Products(
        id_number int auto_increment primary key,
        name nvarchar(50),
        img_path nvarchar(100),
        price nvarchar(10),
        description nvarchar(200),
        publish_year nvarchar(20),
        author_name nvarchar(20)
    )
    """
    
    with sqlite3.connect("Shopping.db") as connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(customers_table)
            cursor.execute(products_table)
            connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            connection.rollback()
```

I tried to used 'regexp' but the interpreter doesn't recognize it while the sql console use it with ease.
I tried: check (phone_number like '0522233355'), and it worked.
I tried: check (phone_number like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'), not working.
I tried different phone numbers, but the same result.
that's what I have tried.

Comment: Can you please link to the documentation of `like`?

Comment: I don't belive the SQL `like` statement uses regular expressions.  Why did you think it does?

Comment: @JohnGordon I saw some uses of it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36045875/constraint-for-phone-number-in-sql-server

Comment: @KellyBundy here it is: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/

Comment: Every instance of using like I've seen uses leading or trailing percent signs, even in the example listed, which you're missing.

Comment: @Phix I'm quoting from https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/: "The percent sign % wildcard matches any sequence of zero or more characters."

Comment: I don't need to use just "like" expression, if anyone have any other solution, I will be grateful to use it

Comment: Right, but you don't have %, i.e. `phone_number like '^[0-9]{10}$'`

Comment: @Phix it didn't work, and it is also not helpful in my condition, if i add these % at the beginning and at the end then the expression will result with "1" on every string with the substring between the two %'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could amend the usages of `LIKE`

```sql
    create table if not exists Customers(
        phone_number nvarchar(10) primary key,
        first_name nvarchar(15),
        last_name nvarchar(15),
        city nvarchar(20),
        address nvarchar(50),
        backup_phone nvarchar(10),
        password nvarchar(20),
        check (length(phone_number) == 10),
        check (phone_number != backup_phone)
        check (phone_number GLOB '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'),
        check (length(password) >= 8 and length(password) <= 20)
     )
```

Given that you are using Python, I would suggest checking the regex with a user defined function in Python, as SQLite is limited in regex capabilities, supporting `{n}` could be done using tricks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64193085/2730737)

For example,

```py
import sqlite3
import re

# Check if a string contains exactly 10 digits
def regex_check(s):
    return re.match(r'^[0-9]{10}$', s) is not None

conn = sqlite3.connect('DATABASE_NAME.db')
conn.create_function("REGEX_CHECK", 1, regex_check)

# Now REGEX_CHECK is usable in SQL, for example
conn.execute("""
    create table if not exists Customers(
        phone_number nvarchar(10) primary key,
        -- other fields
        check (REGEX_CHECK(phone_number))
        -- other constraints
    )
""")
```

Comment: It worked, Thank You very much
the "GLOB" method worked, the other method didn't work with me, it keeps saying "unknown function: REGEX_CHECK" when i store phone number inside
Again Thank You very much